# How do I make a remote connection in college/institute LAN?

Tags: 14.04, remote-desktop

I want to access (and control) the PC in my lab remotely from my own room. Both of them are under the institute LAN and both have Ubuntu 14.04 on them. I require an `LDAP` username and password to login to the Internet and there is no proxy. Although, proxy can be enabled if I want. Sorry if I sound amateurish.

What software should I use? And how do I make it happen?

---

**EDIT :**

I am using Remmina and xrdp as described by Maythux, but the Lemmina window after connection just automatically closes after successful login. What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some Remote Desktop apps: VNC, XRDP , SSH ,etc...

Here I'll explain how to use `xrdp` since I think it's the best for a newbie

First install the package on the target machine if it's not:

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Now you can get the connection to using `Remmina`:

> Remmina is a remote desktop software client for Linux-based computer
>   operating systems. It supports the RDP, VNC, NX, XDMCP and SSH
>   protocols.

Remmina is preshiped with Ubuntu just open your dash and search for Remmina.

Now create a new connection from the Top menu

[image]

Enter the needed entries:

- name it
- Enter the target IP in the server entry
- Enter Username and password
- Change the Resolution as needed or keep the default(target resolution)
- Change the color depth to `True color 32bpp`
- Now press `save` for later use.

Now you can just click the `connect` button and hola you are in.

If you don't like to store your user credentials just leave the username and password field empty so when you click connect you'll see such this:

[image]

So here you can enter your username and password and then OK.

*Be sure to choose **`sesman-X11rdp`** in the module entry.*

---

#### Some useful links

- [How to Install and Configure VNC on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-14-04)
- [SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/Configuring)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What username and password do I need in the above fields? Is it my LDAP id for the institute LAN or the Ubuntu User account ID?